# How to assign "Null" as a value to a string variable in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to import users from Active directory and in one of the cases, the user has a last name as Null. Can I have some pointers as to how should I take this one down?

Comment: Why is this a problem? Is the name in the AD "Null" or is it a null value in the AD?

Comment: They way you state it: `String myString = "null";` `"null"` is a string, `null` is the null value. So again: where's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

That should be no problem, since it will be read as a String with the value `"Null"` not `null`.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about the string `"Null"`; you can use it normally.